# Irreducibility of a certain incidence correspondence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, grassmannian

Let $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$ be four irreducible curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$. We can consider the incidence correspondence of lines that meet 4 automorphisms of these 4 curves:
$$
\Phi = \{(\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3, \varphi_4, L)\in (\operatorname{PGL_4})^{4}\times \mathbb{G}(1,3)\ | \ L\cap \varphi_{i}(B_i)\neq\emptyset \text{ for each } i\}
$$
How can we show that $\Phi$ is irreducible? I can consider the second projection map $\pi_2:\Phi\to \mathbb{G}(1,3)$. Since $\mathbb{G}(1,3)$ is irreducible, it suffices to show that all the fibers of $\pi_2$ are irreducible. This is not clear to me. I am not sure how to understand the fibers $\pi_{2}^{-1}(L)$ for each $L\in \mathbb{G}(1,3)$.

This is Exercise 3.31 (page 127) from "3264 and all that..." by Eisenbud and Harris. You can find a free and legal copy of the book from the [Harvard website.](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiber $\pi_2^{-1}(L)$ is the set of quadruples of automorphisms $(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3,\varphi_4)$ such that $L \cap \varphi_i(B_i)$ is non-empty.

You want to show that this fiber is irreducible.

Note that it is enough to show that $M=\{ \varphi \in PGL_4 \mid L \cap \phi(B) \neq \emptyset \}$ is irreducible, where $B$ is an irreducible curve, since the fiber is the product of four of these.

To prove this, look at another incidence correspondence. Let $\Gamma$ be the set $\{ (\varphi,p) \mid \varphi(p) \in L\} \subset PGL_4 \times B$. Let $\pi_2$ be the projection onto $B$, and $\pi_1$ be the projection onto $PGL_4$. Then $M=\pi_1(\Gamma)$. If we can show that $\Gamma$ is irreducible, we're done.

Let $p \in B$. Then $\pi_2^{-1}(p)$ is the set of automorphisms
$$
\{ \varphi \mid \varphi(p) \in L \} \subset PGL_4
$$

We can for simplicity assume that $L=\{ x_0=x_1=0 \}$. Think of $\varphi$ as a four by four matrix. Then the above equation says that the two first coordinates of $\varphi(p) \in \mathbb P^3$ (thought of as $k^4$), are zero. This is a *linear* equation in the coordinates on $PGL_4$. Since $GL_4$ is just an open subset of $\mathbb A^{n^2}$, and this defines a *linear subspace*, it follows that this defines an irreducible set for all $p \in B$. Hence, since $B$ is irreducible, and the map $\pi_2$ have irreducible fibers of the same dimension, it follows that $\Gamma$ is irreducible.

Hence $\pi_1(\Gamma)$ is irreducible, and so is your $M$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, Fredrik. I have a question: you say "since $B$ is irreducible, and the map $\pi_2$ have generically irreducible fibers, it follows that $\Gamma$ is irreducible." Why is this true? For example, consider the projection map $\pi: \{xy=0\} \to \mathbb{A}^1$ onto the first coordinate. Then $\pi$ has generically irreducible fibers and $\mathbb{A}^1$ is irreducible, but $\{xy=0\}$ is not irreducible.

Comment: In the last big paragraph, maybe it is actually possible that the fibers $\pi_{2}^{-1}$ is irreducible for *every* $p$ (as opposed to generic $p$). If this is the case, then I think the solution is complete. Could you clarify? :)

Comment: @Prism : Thank you for your comment. I was a bit too quick. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I was being a bit sloppy myself. It is not even enough to assume that all fibers are irreducible (as the example above $\{xy=0\}\to \mathbb{A}^1$ shows). We need the fibers to have the same dimension. So we are appealing to the following result: If $f: X\to Y$ is a regular map between projective varieties, such that $Y$ is irreducible, $f^{-1}(p)$ is irreducible for each $p\in Y$ and moreover $\dim f^{-1}(p)=\dim f^{-1}(q)$ for each $p, q\in Y$, *then* $X$ is irreducible. This is Theorem 1.26 in page 76 of Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I".

Comment: In our case, the fibers are linear spaces of the same dimension, so it works! :) Thanks again for this great answer!